# Im still able to intercept x-www-form-urlencoded data after setting up an SSL. Why is that happening?

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

I have configured my express server to work with SSL and a self signed certificate that I installed in my comp.

And for testing purpose im using postman and a traffic analyzer like Burp Suite Community to check the data that is sent to the server.

This analyzer did let me see all the plain text sent to the login endpoint when it was a post to an http login endpoint

But I switched to an https login endpoint, and I still can see the data that is being sent there

If it its over SSL, why is that happening? Isnt it supposed to be unreadable?

Comment: Burp is an active man in the middle - which thus works also for SSL. SSL does not protect against a **trusted** active MITM, i.e. a trusted SSL intercepting proxy. But that's what you are doing. It protects against passive sniffing with Wireshark or similar though.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thats what I was supposing, thanks, its clear now